# couchbase query returning high value on sum

Tags: couchbase, sql++

My document contains 183 of type Person and 2723 documents of type Purchase. Basically, a person buys products. Example documents are as follows. A person might never have purchased anything.

```
{"Type" : "Person", PersonID: 1, InitialFee: 100, "MemberGroupTypeID" : 1, _id:"Person_1_1"},
{"Type" : "Person", PersonID: 2, InitialFee: 200, "MemberGroupTypeID" : 1, _id:"Person_1_1"},
{"Type" : "Purchase", PersonID: 1, PurchaseID:1, Value: 5, "MemberGroupTypeID" : 1, _id:"Purchase_1_1_1"},
{"Type" : "Purchase", PersonID: 1, PurchaseID:2, Value: 10, "MemberGroupTypeID" : 1, _id:"Purchase_2_1_1"},
{"Type" : "Purchase", PersonID: 1, PurchaseID:3, Value: 25, "MemberGroupTypeID" : 1, _id:"Purchase_3_1_1"}
```

Basically, the output expected is:

```
MemberGroupTypeID: 1, FeesTotal: 300, TotalPurchasesCost: 40
```

I have the following query which returns correct total purchase cost for each type of members group but the FeesTotal is way too high and I don't know how it is getting that number by all means. I mean, I couldn't spot a relationship between the expected number and the actual FeesTotal I am getting after running the query:

```
SELECT SUM(person.InitialFee) AS FeesTotal,
SUM(purchase.Value) as TotalPurchasesCost,
person.MemberGroupTypeID
FROM bucket person
LEFT JOIN bucket purchase
ON person.MemberGroupTypeID= purchase.MemberGroupTypeID
WHERE person.Type = "Person" AND purchase.Type = "Purchase" AND
person.PersonId = purchase.PersonId
GROUP BY person.MemberGroupTypeID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When JOIN each Left Side can produce 1:n. If you aggregate then it counted multiple times.

Use two level aggregation by grouping whole left side document first then group the desired fields.

```
SELECT b.MemberGroupTypeID,
       SUM(b.InitialFee) AS FeesTotal,
       SUM(b.PurchasesCost) AS TotalPurchasesCost,
FROM (SELECT person.InitialFee,
             person.MemberGroupTypeID,
             SUM(purchase.`Value`) AS PurchasesCost
       FROM bucket AS person
       LEFT JOIN bucket AS purchase
       ON person.MemberGroupTypeID = purchase.MemberGroupTypeID
          AND purchase.Type = "Purchase" AND person.PersonId = purchase.PersonId
       WHERE person.Type = "Person"
       GROUP BY person) AS b
GROUP BY b.MemberGroupTypeID;
```

Comment: Thanks @vsr. Worked wel. Just curious: what does two level aggregation mean exactly? Sorry. It is 2am here.

Comment: Nested Aggregates (i.e argument of aggregate can't depend on another aggregate) are not allowed. Same thing you can achieved by intervening subquery

Comment: Thanks @vsr. The features are not part of CBL I assume?

Comment: If you are looking in CBL next time tag as CBL